# How to fix the mismatched records in snowflake tables and local (source) sql db tables?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I looked through existing questions, but didn’t find anything similar.

I took over a snowflake file loading process that loads files from s3, after tables were already initially loaded (the subsequent loads are daily deltas) and added a file with the source tables record counts to the process. The process now compares the loaded tables record counts to the source tables record counts and there is a small number of tables that do not match, the count difference is from 1 record to 3 thousand, some tables are pretty large with 3-6 million records.

I need to figure out what missing/extra records are in snowflake tables and add/remove to match the source tables.

IDs in tables are identity auto incremented fields in the source db.
I guess I could try unloading ID+some record identifying fields into files from snowflake then loading them into the source db and comparing records there. Is that the only solution?

Comment: Do you know if the discrepancy is between your source and your S3 files or between your S3 files and Snowflake. Assuming you have a Stage defined over your S3 files you can query them, so comparing them to what's in your Snowflake tables should be relatively straightforward

Comment: @NickW files in the s3 stage are daily deltas - changes from yesterday. I have all the files that were loaded after the initial load, about 300 for each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you specify the file loading process that loads files from s3?
Using 3rd party tools like Airbyte or Fivetran is very useful for the ingestion without the need to handle duplicates, retries, etc.
As the first step, Ensure you don't have duplications in the target table.

For comparing databases across different sources, I would suggest something like https://github.com/datafold/data-diff
It is very efficient since it is using hashes for the comparisons.
Unfortunately, it does not support S3 files, so, I wonder if this is your source, if not you can create external tables from it and use these for the comparison.

Comment: I am not using any 3rd party tools, I use DAG of tasks to load files in batches from our external stage. Data-diff looks interesting. Thanks. Have you used it? I’m new to Snowflake and don’t want to run over the daily credits comparing tables.

Comment: Yes. Data-diff is great. It should not take a lot of credits as it aggregates the hash instead of comparing each value separately.